# Accessing SQL Azure from client app

Tags: azure, visual-c++, azure-sql-database

We have a client app that uses a database for it's data storage. It typically performs CRUD operations on them (SQL Server, Oracle, SQL Azure ...). Typically this app is installed on end users laptops, and it talks directly to the database (no middleware).

We have tested our app with SQL Azure previously and it works well. However, the one stumbling block we see is that we need to pinhole ourselves in to the Azure firewall to allow access.

Our clients would typically be accessing Azure from various locations with variable IP addresses, is there any way to allow them to securely access Azure using our app without compromising security or imposing a huge administrative burden managing the Azure firewall?

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 2):

If you want to provide access directly to the database from different locations you will need to add the rule to open your firewall to connect to the server or database level. Maybe, this is not the best solution in security terms but is the only if you want to expose your DB to your app.

[image: Azure SQL Server and Database firewall rules].

A better idea would be to create an API between the app and your database that exposes the data. Every client makes the requests to your API and they are validated there. If is a registered user the API gets the information from the DB and exposes it to your clients. It may require more work but it would make it easier for you to keep your security in control and extend or modified it in the future.

If you want more details about the Azure SQL Firewall you can check this article from the MSDN: [How to configure an Azure SQL database firewall](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-firewall-configure/).

Comment: What about using Azure VPN - would that work? Then you would have a fixed range of IPs?

Comment: I know that you can mark the check to make the database available to other Azure Services, I don't know if it includes an Azure VPN. You should try :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't solved this as such, but I've found a different approach that may be useful to others.

I have deployed my app on Azure Remote App and set up an SQL Azure database as the storage engine for it.

This works well, and has the added advantage of user management, we can use Microsoft logins to control access to our account, removing the need for firewall pinholing.

Comment: It is great that you provided a solution. Just wondering, does each user gets to pay for using the application with this approach? I think so.